# Bold chinese characters with ctex

Tags: chinese, ctex

I am doing some document with Chinese characters and package `ctex`

```
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
```

However, as soon as I try to typeset something in bold, say

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\textbf{固态}};
\end{tikzpicture}

I immediately get error

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file simhei.ttf): cannot open TrueType font file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Inbetween there are also some warnings

```
File: CJK.enc 2015/04/18 4.8.4
Now handling font encoding C00 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C00
Now handling font encoding C05 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C05
Now handling font encoding C09 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding C09
etc.
```

I am using `miktex`.

Now the problem is that all the documentation is in Chinese, but I don't speak any...

Comment: You need font `simhei.ttf`, which is one of the commercial fonts installed with Windows.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ OK, I have checked, I don't have it (probably because I don't have Chinese Windows).  So should I download it (Google found plenty of free SimHei fonts) and put it somewhere in tex font directory and run `updmap`?

Comment: You should be able to install Chinese fonts as an optional feature from the Apps and Features control panel.

Comment: If you compile your document with LuaLaTeX, `ctex` will use `luatexja` to load fonts, which does have [English documentation.](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/luatexja/doc/luatexja-en.pdf)

Comment: By itself `ctex` has a `fontset=` option, which can take the values `adobe|fandol|founder|mac|macnew|macold|ubuntu|windows|none`

Comment: Finally: if neither of us can actually read the manual in Chinese, it is very likely that we only need to copy and paste a few short Chinese phrases into a document primarily in our native language. The `babel` package suffices for that.

Comment: @Davislor I tried with `\usepackage[chinese]{babel}` instead of `ctex` and it did not work at all.  Because I would like to stay in my comfort zone (`pdflatex`) I will try to install Chinese characters and use `fontset=windows`.

Comment: You’ve run into one of the big problems with `babel`, which is that some of the package options are obsolete and you need to use `\babelprovide` instead. I convinced Javier Bezos to update the documentation.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks.  Just installing Chinese fonts on Features helped  (Using `fontset` was not necessary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ctex` package has a `fontset=` option, which supports the values

```
adobe|fandol|founder|mac|macnew|macold|ubuntu|windows|none
```

On Windows, you can install Chinese fonts as an optional feature from the Apps and Features control panel.  This will use SimSun.  I compiled in LuaLaTeX rather than PDFLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8, fontset=windows]{ctex}

\begin{document}
regular 固态

\textbf{bold 固态}
\end{document}
```

[image: SimSun font sample]

Examining the source on page 66 of [the manual,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/chinese/ctex/ctex.pdf) which, unlike Chinese, I am able to read, `ctex` defines the command `\setCJKmainfont`, which you can use to set an arbitrary font.  (It also has `\setCJKsansfont` and `\setCJKmonofont`.) This would allow someone on another OS to compile your document and get the same output.  This works on either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8, fontset=none]{ctex}

\setCJKmainfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\begin{document}
regular 固态

\textbf{bold 固态}
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Serif CJK SC sample]

However, if neither of us can read a manual in Chinese, it is highly likely that all we really need (or I am capable of) is to copy-and-paste some short Chinese phrases into a document in our native language.  The `babel` package is good for that.  This requires LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\babelprovide[import=zh-Hans, onchar=ids fonts]{chinese}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures={Common,Discretionary}, Scale=1.0]{New Computer Modern Book}
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}
          {Noto Serif CJK SC}

\begin{document}
regular 固态

\textbf{bold 固态}
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern + Noto Serif CJK SC sample]

It even can switch between Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese, Japanese Kanji, and more, in the same document.

In your comment, you mention that you ran into one of the big problems with `babel`: many of its package options are obsolete, and you must use `\babelprovide` to load some languages instead.  As I write, Javier Bezos is currently updating the documentation to warn users about this.

Comment: Such a nice one `+1`